# How to show root folders in file tree in cloud9 local ssh install

Tags: ssh, cloud9-ide

I've installed cloud9 locally on my remote sever following instructions from Cloud9's "sdkcore" repository on github.

I was able to activate it correctly.

However, once started, the files tree only shows Cloud9 folders, but if you want to edit a file contained in a `/var/www/examplefolder` directory, I cannot.

I could only modify through the ssh terminal, but I would like to be able to edit the files using the most convenient sublime editor.

[image: cloud9 file tree]

How can i fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**update:**

I resolved creating a link with the command :

```
sudo ln -s /path/from/folder/you/need  /path/to/c9/workspace
```

in that way you will see your files in c9 workspace folder in the file tree bar;

or

```
sudo ln -s /path/from/folder/you/need  /home/yourusername/
```

in that way you will see your files in favourites folder in the file tree bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, you'll need to create the SSH workspace with the workspace root as `/` . Alternately, you can open files in the IDE by using the `c9 {filename}` command.

Comment: Hi, I tried using  `c9 {filename}`  but it doesn't work. Are you sure that the `c9` command is not deprecated? However , the terminal says"command not found".

Comment: Run `npm install -g c9` first, followed by `c9 {filename}`